# jquery can't alert ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

I'm trying to alert the Ajax response from the code below but somehow nothing gets alerted.

```
    function get_fee(){
        if ( $('#type').val() == 'hardcopy' ) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                var title = $('#title').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'convert.php',
                    data: {hardcopy: '1', title: title},
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response == 'false') {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

However, if the above code was written without

```
    if (response == 'false') {

    }
```

and the `alert( response )` is called, it works flawlessly. I would have adopted the later approach but unfortunately the value of `var response` can either be true or false.

Comment: is `response` a boolean?

Comment: what is your response holding

Comment: write `conlose.log(response)` and update question with result

Comment: Can you write Response Object?

Comment: @DanielA.White the response is a boolean

Comment: console.log(response) has no value @teovankot

Comment: @ebuka youre testing against a `string` not a `boolean`

Comment: No ... the response is a string .... it might represent a boolean value when transformed, but is a string until then. What exactly is being sent?

Comment: @Craicerjack The response is a string with value 'false'.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. If the response is a boolean all you're going to do is log that out.

If you're trying to handle an error, why not use the error callback of $.ajax?

Comment: @ebuka you said to DanielA that the response was a `boolean`. I think it would be a good idea to show what the actual response is.

Comment: @Craicerjack it was an error. What i meant was a false (not in the boolean sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem.
The response returns a string as value rather than a boolean. 
So I changed its data type to boolean before it is received by ajax (from 'false' with quotes to false without quotes), and i was able to evaluate it as a boolean with

```
if (response == false) {
    alert(response);
}
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Comment: It is same as mine.

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

```
if (response) {
       alert(response);
} else { alert("Some Error Message"); }
```

Comment: why alert something that doesn't exist?

Comment: Nice. Now exist.

Comment: @hamzox the alert does not still show up with your code

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking off the quotes from around the 'false'

```
   if (response == false) {

    }
```

or just

```
   if (!response) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need the double (" ") quotes for a boolean value.

   ```
   if (response == false) {
     alert(response); 
   }
   ```
2. You can use:

   ```
    error: function(response){
       alert(response); 
    }
   ```

Comment: The ajax echoes either true or false as response so i enclosed the values with double quotes before it is echoed.

Comment: I understand, but why not use complement ( ! ) as if(!response) instead of the boolean true/false?

Comment: The issue has been solved. i changed it to a boolean value as in true (without the quotes)  and it worked well. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the strings `"true"` or `"false"`,  try removing extra whitespace that could be there from php file:

```
if (response.trim() == 'false') {
   alert(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have following options
Use any one from them :

1) As for boolean comparison dont use speech marks so use false instead of 'false'

if (response == false) {

```
}
```

2) directly use response for decision making

if (!response) {

```
}
```

3) if (response == false)
   alert("whatever you wish to put")

4) if (!response)
   alert("whatever you wish to put")

Comment: The response is a string but has the value of false. So basically, i can't use false as in the Boolean format

Comment: then try using === instead of ==

Comment: response is a string with value false. So i can't evaluate response using it as a boolean as the other value of response when it is not false is also a string.

Comment: if your response is string use this :                                                              
 if (response === "false") {
      alert("yes we got it");
 }